# Filtrar o mês dentro de um objeto extraído com Object.keys

Tags: javascript, react

Estou estudando react e fiz uma aplicação de fluxo de caixa usando firebase como banco de dados. Eu gostaria de realizar uma consulta, usando o **"map()"** ou outro jeito que percorresse o objeto mostrando somente as entradas do mês de **mar**, mas estou encontrando dificuldade para realizar esta tarefa, tendo em vista que estraio a consulta usando **Object.keys**. Abaixo esta o exemplo de como fica o objeto após extraido.

```
const keysIn = Object.keys(this.props.inflow);

let entrada =  JSON.stringify(keysIn);


console.log(entrada)

// O retorno do console.log fica assim
 {
    '1': {
      month: 'fev',
      name: 'xxxxxxx',
      value: 300,
    },
    '2': {
      month: 'mar',
      name: 'yyyyyyyy',
      value: 500,
    },
    '3': {
      month: 'mar',
      name: 'zzzz',
      value: 400,
    },
  }
```

Comment: Mas tem certeza que você quer usar o `map` e não o `filter`?

Comment: Não é necessario não, pensei neles porque preciso percorrer o objeto e mostrar todos que contenham o mes "mar".

Comment: Fora que é meio esquisito o `console.log` retornar um objeto para a variável `entrada` já que o `Objects.keys` retorna um `array`. Você tem certeza disso?

Comment: No caso a variavel de entrada recebe o JSON.stringfy(keysIn), então ela passa a ser um objeto, eu até fiz um **typeof** para tirar a duvida .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso você pode utilizar o `map` para formar um `array` e após isso utilizar o `filter` para manter apenas os que estão com `mar` no atributo `month`:

```js
const original = {
  '1': {
    month: 'fev',
    name: 'xxxxxxx',
    value: 300,
  },
  '2': {
    month: 'mar',
    name: 'yyyyyyyy',
    value: 500,
  },
  '3': {
    month: 'mar',
    name: 'zzzz',
    value: 400,
  },
};

// Pega apenas as chaves dos atributos
const chaves = Object.keys(original);
// Transforma o objeto em array baseado nas chaves
const todos = chaves.map((chave) => original[chave]);
// Filtra aqueles com a propriedade month igual a "mar"
const filtrados = todos.filter((item) => item.month === 'mar');

console.log(filtrados);
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora entendi a lógica que precisava fazer. ✌️